# "/bin/sh: 1: [“apache2ctl”,: not found" in docker

Tags: bash, docker, apache2

I have a simple Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y apache2
RUN apt-get install -y apache2-utils
RUN apt-get clean
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
EXPOSE 80
CMD [“apache2ctl”, “-D FOREGROUND”]
```

I build it with the following statement

```
docker build -t mywebserver .
```

That works quite well, but when I want to execute it with

```
docker run -p 80:80 mywebserver
```

it returns the error message you can see in the headline.
I also tried `/usr/sbin/apache2ctl` instead of `apache2ctl` to make sure that it is not because of missing in the `PATH` but that did not help.

So thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You have typographic quotes in CMD (`“ ”`), use straight quotes (`"`).

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have typographic quotes in CMD (“ ”), use straight quotes ("). – Dan Lowe

Comment: This is the issue, and it's on both the top two results in google for building a dockerfile/webserver lol

Answer (score 3):

change this line

`CMD [“apache2ctl”, “-D FOREGROUND”]`

to

`CMD ["apache2ctl", "-D","FOREGROUND"]`

You should group your RUN, by the way, see

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/