# Docker /user/sbin/apache2ctl: not found

Tags: laravel, apache, docker

This issue is not a duplicate of [“/bin/sh: 1: “apache2ctl”,: not found” in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45082745/bin-sh-1-apache2ctl-not-found-in-docker)

This is a simple docker file I used for laravel framework in a ubuntu operating system.

```
version : '3'

services:
  web: 
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}_web
    build:
      context: ./docker/web
    ports:
      - 9000:80
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/app
```

And this is the docker file located in docker/web

```
FROM php:7.2.10-apache-stretch

RUN apt-get update -yqq && \
    apt-get install -y apt-utils zip unzip && \
    apt-get install -y nano && \
    apt-get install -y libzip-dev libpq-dev && \
    a2enmod rewrite && \
    docker-php-ext-install pdo_pgsql && \
    docker-php-ext-install pgsql && \
    docker-php-ext-configure zip --with-libzip && \
    docker-php-ext-install zip && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN php -r "readfile('http://getcomposer.org/installer');"|php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin --filename=composer

COPY Default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

WORKDIR /var/www/app

EXPOSE 80

CMD ['/usr/sbin/apache2ctl', '-D', 'FOREGROUND']
```

When I run this command

```
sudo docker-compose up
```

Terminal Output is this error

```
Starting Docker_Laravel_web ... done
Attaching to Docker_Laravel_web
Docker_Laravel_web | /bin/sh: 1: [/usr/sbin/apache2ctl,: not found
Docker_Laravel_web exited with code 127
```

Need some help to fix this,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Dockerfile syntax, where it has things that look like JSON lists, isn't actually JSON, and is fairly picky about its quoting.  In particular, in your final line

```
CMD ['/usr/sbin/apache2ctl', '-D', 'FOREGROUND']
```

you must use double quotes

```
CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

otherwise Docker interprets it as the "run a shell on this command" form, which is why you see the `[` and `,` in your error message.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like didn't install apache application

you should add 1 more command line in RUN

`apt-get install -y apache2 &&\`

Comment: No, Apache2 is available in the image

Comment: maybe you can run `CMD ["apache2", '-D', 'FOREGROUND']`

Comment: Docker_Laravel_web | [Sat Nov 17 23:00:15.344434 2018] [core:warn] [pid 1] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_DIR} is not defined

Docker_Laravel_web | apache2: Syntax error on line 80 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: DefaultRuntimeDir must be a valid directory, absolute or relative to ServerRoot

Comment: I think problem is your config

Comment: I fixed it with answer above. Thank you very much for your help!